# Finding a good data type for parsing data in python for downstream analyses

Tags: python, r, csv

I come from an R background but am trying to make the transition to Python so I can share my programs with other individuals who aren't programmatically inclined. I'd really like your opinion on how to approach this problem:

I begin by reading a .csv into Python and parsing its contents while omitting any manual annotation contained within the .csv.

This results in a 'list' in python containing all my numeric data linearly, but I would like to structure the data so I could analyze columns/rows much like in R.

The data look like:

```
for m in range(0, 4):
    print(str(data[(m*7):((m*7)+7)]))

['1.8069', '2.0448', '0.0145', '2.0701', '1.8375', '2.0178', '0.0173']
['0.8059', '1.2591', '0.0149', '1.5549', '0.9937', '2.0174', '0.0175']
['0.3055', '0.6657', '0.012', '0.6142', '0.3991', '1.5143', '0.0164']
['0.1065', '0.1715', '0.017', '0.2163', '0.1391', '1.0154', '0.0152']
['0.0492', '0.0704', '0.0168', '0.0792', '0.0592', '0.8143', '0.0143']
```

Please note that these data are the result of a biochemical assay (ELISA), and are serially diluted downward (that's why the top values get smaller as they go down-- the scale is logarithmic).

In R, I may begin to parse these data with a for-loop and a list, maybe something like:

```
list <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
    list[[i]] <- data[,i] #All rows of column i go into list entry i
}
```

and then I could do downstream analyses, like finding the most remarkable responses (the numbers with the highest magnitude), again, in R, something like:

```
positives <- list()
for (i in 1:length(list)){
    positives[[i]] <- max(list[[i]]) #Pulling out the maximum response from each entry
}
```

The problem is that, from any one .csv, there could be any number of ELISA data, any number positive responses, and I don't know of a Python data type that may be best suited for the task of sifting through the data and finding the positive responses.

I've seen things like dictionaries and arrays, but I don't know if there's a neat trick for these kinds of things that I'm missing because I don't know what I don't know.

Do you folks have any thoughts? I don't really need anyone to do any programming for me, just if they could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) is a very good equivalent of R dataframes.